# How are main net and test net blockchain state migrated to new protocols?

Tags: protocol, testnet, upgrade

As far as I know protocol updates are made on main net about every 3 months. When this happens all balances, smart contracts, and smart contract state are preserved on main net. But how does it work on test net, is the existing state on the old protocol on test net abandoned and a new instance of a test net blockchain started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the old testing networks are abandoned and brand new networks are launched using the new to-be-activated protocol.

For instance, Carthagenet will be deactivated on 12/12/2020. The current Delphinet test network will remain as a protocol copy of mainnet. Edonet was launched yesterday, which is using the upcoming beta 008 protocol.

Comment: So for test net a new genesis block is baked upon protocol upgrades. Makes sense. Which of those test networks tend to be the most popular, the protocol copy of mainnet, or the one with the upcoming protocol?

Comment: I'd say the protocol copy of mainnet (delphinet) since most people want to test against current main without risks. Please mark as answered if good.

Comment: What was launched yesterday is called ebetanet. It’s a short lived test net before edonet which will be launched in approximately two weeks.